# how to use RANDOM command in declared array

Tags: arrays, bash, password-generator

I am trying to build a script where I need to  create a password generator with the following parameters :

- must be at least 8 characters long but not longer than 16 characters.
- must contain at least 1 digit (0-9).
- must contain at least 1 lowercase letter.
- must contain at least 1 uppercase letter.
- must contain exactly one and only one of `@ #  $  %  &  *  +  -  =`

  ---

I have two ideas :

The first :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#Password Generator 
#
#

Upper=('A''B''C''D''E''F''G''H''I''J'K''L''M''N''O''P''Q''R''S''T''U''V''W''X''Y''Z')
Lower=('a''b''c''d''e''z''f''g''h''i''j''k''l''m''o'''p''q''r''s''t''u''v''w''x''y''z')
Numbers=('1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9')
SpecialChar=('@''#''$''%''&''*''+''-''=')



if [ S# -eq 0 ] ; then 


Pwlength=`shuf -i 8-16 -n 1` 

Password=`< /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9$SpecialChar | head -c $Pwlength` 

echo "Random Password is being generated for you"

sleep 5

echo "Your new password  is : $Password"


exit
```

The problem is I get characters that I didnt even defined ?

The secound idea :

```
for((i=0;i<4;i++)) 

do

password=${Upper[$random % ${#Lower[@]} ] }
password=${Upper[$random % ${#Upper[@]} ] }
password=${Upper[$random % ${#Number[@]} ] }
password=${Upper[$random % ${#SpecialChar[@]} ] }

done
```

For some reason non of them work ;/

Comment: It is `$RANDOM`, not `$random`.

Comment: `$SpecialChar` does not expand to the contents of the array `"${SpecialChar[@]}"` and because it contains shell metacharacters, it needs to be double quoted like I showed in order for the shell not to react to those metacharacters (expand any wildcard matches, etc).

Comment: Really, what's the point of the `sleep 5`??

Comment: Anyway, using an array of a single string is very pointless.  After removal of quotes, `'A''B''C'` is equivalent to `'ABC'`.

Comment: :~/bin> UPPER=("A""B""C""D""E""F""G""H""I""J""K""L""M""N""O""P""Q""R""S""T""U""V""W""X""Y""Z")

Comment: You just want `upper=(A B C D ...)`, etc. You only need to quote single characters that the shell would treat specially. Upper- and lower-case letters and numbers can be left unquoted, and there's no harm in leaving all the special characters quoted. You *must*, however, separate them with unquoted whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, move the "-" character to the end of the SpecialChar. I think the definition as you had it results in allowing "+" to "=" (i.e., the value passed to tr reads as "+-="), which accounts for the characters you were not expecting. Alternatively, replace the "-" with "_".

```
So, try a definition like:
SpecialChar=('@''#''$''%''&''*''+''=''-')
```

Comment: you were right about that special character positions. I made a change and it works now . About the other method, I want to understand  what part do I have to quote ? password="${Upper[$random % ${#Upper[@]}" ] }

Comment: I want use RANDOM to mix the character in the array and give me one character which will be added to the "Password" variable  I have to make it run through  all arrays in a for  four times so I can have 16 characters

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt has the following problems:

- You are using arrays to contain single strings.  Pasting `'A''B''C'` is equivalent to `'ABC'`.  Simply converting these to scalar variables would probably be the simplest fix.
- You are not [quoting your variables](//stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable).
- You declare `Upper`, `Lower`, and `Numbers`, but then never use them.
- Using variables for stuff you only ever use once (or less :-) is dubious anyway.
- As noted by @KevinO, the dash has a special meaning in `tr`, and needs to be first or last if you want to match it literally.

On top of that, the `sleep 5` doesn't seem to serve any useful purpose, and will begin to annoy you if it doesn't already.  If you genuinely want a slower computer, I'm sure there are people here who are willing to trade.

Your second attempt has the following problems:

- The special variable `$RANDOM` in Bash is spelled in all upper case.
- You are trying to do modulo arithmetic on (unquoted!) arrays of characters, which isn't well-defined.  The divisor after `%` needs to be a single integer.  You can convert character codes to integers but it's sort of painful, and it's less than clear what you hope for the result to be.

A quick attempt at fixing the first attempt would be

```
Password=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9@#$%&*+=-' | head -c $(shuf -i 8-16 -n 1))
```

If you want to verify some properties on the generated password, I still don't see why you would need arrays.

```
while read -r category expression; do
    case $Password in
      *[$expression]*) continue;;
      *) echo "No $category"; break;;
    esac
done <<'____HERE'
    lowercase a-z
    uppercase A-Z
    numbers   0-9
    specials  -@#$%&*+=
HERE
```

Comment: I declare an array because later I have to use it against the passwords to verify the password rules

Comment: Then you need spaces between the individual elements when you initialize. Your code doesn't show how you are trying to use the arrays, so unfortunately, I can't tell how to fix this part of the code. `tr` requires a single string in any event.

Comment: If your current code uses arrays, it doesn't really, and converting it to use regular scalars may still be the simplest fix.

Answer (score 0):

- As already mentioned, it would be cleaner and easier to use directly a string to handle list of characters. Handling special characters in an array may cause side effects (for instance getting the list of files in the current directory with the '*' character). In addition, arrays may be difficult to pass as function arguments).

  ```
  ALPHA_LOW="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

  # Then simply access the char in the string at the ith position
  CHAR=${ALPHA_LOW:$i:1}
  ```
- You could generate upper cases from the lower cases.

  ```
  ALPHA_UP="`echo \"$ALPHA_LOW\" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`"
  ```
- The variable which contains a random number is `$RANDOM` (in capital letters).
- `sleep 5` is unnecessary.
- You need to find a way to keep count of occurrences left for each character type. For more information, I wrote a complete script to do what you described [here](https://github.com/jyvet/strongpass).

Comment: I have opened another post for the whole script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524872/check-single-character-in-array-bash-for-password-generator?noredirect=1#comment60655086_36524872