# Check single character in array bash for password generator

Tags: arrays, bash, random

I am trying to test User input with password rules.

- must be at least 8 characters long but not longer than 16 characters.
- must contain at least 1 digit (0-9).
- must contain at least 1 lowercase letter.
- must contain at least 1 uppercase letter.
- must contain exactly one and only one of `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `*`, `+`, `-`, `=`.

I'm trying to figure how I can compare the user string to the arrays that contain the password characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

Upper=("A""B""C""D""E""F""G""H""I""J""K""L""M""N""O""P""Q""R""S""T""U""V""W""X""Y""Z")
Lower=("a""b""c""d""e""f""g""h""i""j""k""l""m""o""p""q""r""s""t""u""v""w""x""y""z")
Numbers=("1""2""3""4""5""6""7""8""9")
SpecialChar=("&""@""#""$""%""*""-""+""=")

# Password Generator

PassGen(){      # generate password if no user input

Pwlength=`shuf -i 8-16 -n 1`  # holds the range/length of password

Password=`< /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9$SpecialChar | head -c $Pwlength` 

echo "Random Password is being generated for you"
sleep 5

echo "Your new password  is : $Password"
echo exit?

}
# I want to make the following to work :

\#PassGen2(){ # generate password  2 if no user input
\#if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
\#for ((i=0;i<4;i++)) 
\#do    
\#password="${Upper[$random % ${#Upper[@]}" ] }
\#password="${Lower[$random % ${#Lower[@]}" ] }
\#password="${Numbers[$random % ${#Numbers[@]}" ] } 
\#done  
\#password="${SpecialChar[$random % ${#SpecialChar[@]}" ] }
\#password="${Upper[$random % ${#Upper[@]}" ] }

\#echo "Random Password is being generated for you"
\#sleep 5

\#echo "Your new password  is : $Password"

\#fi
\#echo exit?
\#}
# Help menu

Usage(){ # Help menu 

echo "The password must meet the following :"
echo "> must be at least 8 characters long but not longer than 16 characters."
echo "> must contain at least 1 digit (0-9)."
echo "> must contain at least 1 lowercase letter."
echo "> must contain at least 1 uppercase letter."
echo "> must contain exactly one and only one of @ #  $  %  &  *  +  -  ="
echo ""
echo " * * IF NO PASSWORD IS ENTERED THE SYSTEM WILL GENERATE A PASSPORD FOR YOU * * "

echo exit?

}   


#The main starts here

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then 

PassGen $SpecialChar

fi

if [ $# == "-h"] ; then

Usage

fi


UserPW=$1 # assigning the firsth positional parameter to variable (password)

#The reason I open the post     
PwCheck(){   

    if [[ ${#UserPW} < 8 && ${#UserPW} > 0 ]] ;then  #check the lower end of the password 

    echo "Password have to be more then 8 character"
    exit 1
    fi
    if [[ ${#UserPW} < 16 ]] ;then #checks if the password bigger then 16 character

    echo "Password too long ! - Password have to be between 8 - 16 characters"

    exit 1
    fi

    if [[ ${#UserPW} < 17 && ${#UserPW} > 8 ]] ; then 

    Pwarr=($UserPW) # putting the variable into Array 

        for (( i=0; i < ${#Upper[@]};i++ ))  
        do

            if [[ ${Pwarr[0]:[i]:1} != ${Upper[i]} ]]; then
            echo "You have to enter at least 1 upper character letter" 
            exit 1
            fi
        done
        for (( i=0; i < ${#Lower[@]};i++ ))
        do
            if [[ ${Pwarr[0]:[i]:1} != ${Lower[i] ]]; then
            echo "You have to enter at least 1 Lower character letter"
            exit 1
            fi
        done
        for (( i=0; i < ${#SpecialChar[@];i++ ))
        do
            if [[ ${Pwarr[0]:[i]:1} != ${SpecialChar[i] ]] ;then
            echo " You have to enter at least 1 special character 
            exit 1
            fi
        done

    #}
```

My problems:

1. I couldn't make my `PassGen2()` to work beside "calling it". I know
   there must be typo or syntax errors.
2. For  `PwCheck()`   function I know I didn't call it and the IF
   statement should be in the main section.

Comment: Your 'array' initializations are setting a single element in the array.  You'd need spaces between the elements, as in `Upper=("A" "B" "C" … "Z")`.  Your `\#` notation is weird.  Your code is not an MCVE ([MCVE]) by a large margin.  You need to radically simplify what you've shown here.  I'm not sure you should exit when the user breaks one of your rules — and exit in a function exits the program, not the function.

Comment: I wrote some bash-based password checking logic for Asterisk a little while back. Feel free to use any of it that seems useful. https://github.com/chvostek/shelltools/blob/master/voicemailpasswordcheck

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  the \# its to cancel this special character effect on this post

Comment: If you're posting code to SO, (1) make sure it doesn't have tabs in (the copy of) the original, (2) copy'n'paste the tabless code into the edit window, and ignore the preview while you do this, (3) select the code, (4) use the **`{}`** button above the edit window to indent the material as code all at once (and now pay attention to the preview).  If your problem was that the `#` at start-of-line was making level 1 (big!) headings, this will fix that (and 'ignore the preview' is very important).  Please edit your code to replace the `\#` sequences with just `#` now they're indented.

Comment: @ghoti  can you please refer me to a guide that can explian  :[[ 012345678901234567890 == *"$newpass"* ]]- what is  *"$array"* ? I have seen it before but I didnt know how to define it in words to google.

Comment: @jonathanleffler thank you

Comment: Use back-ticks around code quoting in comments.  You asked about `[[ 012345678901234567890 == *"$newpass"* ]]` (note that the `*` normally makes stuff *italic* (`**` makes it **bold**, and yes, `***` makes it ***bold italic***).  That's using a Bash built-in test command and shell globbing to find out if there's some sort of match with the value in `$newpass`.  It's not immediately clear why there are three `0` and two of every other digit.  You need to get familiar with the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) — bookmark it (I have it bookmarked).

Comment: Does it have to be pure bash? Why not call out to Perl or Python?

Comment: @jpmc26 because I dont know those languages, and I am still learning

Comment: Bash is a fantastic language, but when things start getting complicated, I start considering other languages. Perl and Python play quite nicely with bash, but they have more flexibility in their nuts and bolts and more existing libraries.

Comment: To backup @jpmc26: Languages like Perl, Python, Ruby, and even awk, make string handling much easier.  Shells have to perform two conflicting tasks - act as a command-line interpreter (CLI) and act as a programming language.  The programming language part suffers because of restrictions imposed by the CLI part.  Those other languages are not constrained in that way.  Generally it is *harder* to solve complex problems in `bash` than in a non-shell programming language.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to implement PwCheck leaving the user password as a string rather than converting it to an array:

```
bad_length(){
  l=`wc -c`
  [ $l -ge 8 ] && [ $l -le 16 ] && return 1 || return 0
}

no_digit(){
  grep -q '[0-9]' && return 1 || return 0
}

no_lc(){
  grep -q '[a-z]' && return 1 || return 0
}

no_uc(){
  grep -q '[A-Z]' && return 1 || return 0
}

specials='@#$%&*+=-'
no_exactly_one_special(){
  n=`grep -o "[$specials]" | wc -l`
  [ $n -eq 1 ] && return 1 || return 0
}

echo "$1" | bad_length && echo 'Password must be between 8 - 16 characters' && exit 1
echo "$1" | no_digit && echo 'Password must have at least one number 0-9' && exit 1
echo "$1" | no_lc && echo 'Password must have at least one lowercase letter' && exit 1
echo "$1" | no_uc && echo 'Password must have at least one UPPERCASE letter' && exit 1
echo "$1" | no_exactly_one_special && echo "Password must have exactly one special character: $specials" && exit 1
exit 0
```

A few words of explanation:

First, it is possible in bash to pipe (using |) to a function:

```
no_digit_from_stdin(){
  grep -q '[0-9]' && return 1 || return 0
}
echo "abc" | no_digit_from_stdin && echo $?
```

instead of passing it as an argument:

```
no_digit_from_arg(){
  echo "$1" | grep -q '[0-9]' && return 1 || return 0
}
no_digit_from_arg "abc" && echo $?
```

These two have the same outcome here.

Second, it is possible to use pipes and && to control flow concisely. So this:

```
echo "$1" | no_digit_from_stdin && echo 'Password must have at least one number 0-9' && exit 1
```

has the same outcome as this:

```
if no_digit_from_arg "$1"; then
   echo 'Password must have at least one number 0-9'
   exit 1
fi
```

...but these are matters of style and not directly relevant to your question.

Here is a version of my answer that you may find more usable, with a secret bonus feature:

```
PwCheck(){

    pass=true

    l=`echo "$UserPW" | wc -c`
    if [ $l -lt 8 ] || [ $l -gt 16 ]; then
        echo 'Password must be between 8 - 16 characters'
        pass=false
    fi

    if ! echo "$UserPW" | grep -q '[0-9]'; then
        echo 'Password must have at least one number 0-9'
        pass=false
    fi

    if ! echo "$UserPW" | grep -q '[a-z]'; then
        echo 'Password must have at least one lowercase letter'
        pass=false
    fi

    if echo "$UserPW" | grep -q '[A-Z]'; then
        echo 'Password must have at least one UPPERCASE letter'
        pass=false
    fi

    specials='@#$%&*+=-'
    n=`echo "$UserPW" | grep -o "[$specials]" | wc -l`
    if [ $n -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Password must have exactly one special character: $specials"
        pass=false
    fi

    if $pass; then
        exit 0
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your script

Comment: @isRealistic Standard response to 90% of the code you will encounter. ;) Even when you *do* know the language features.

Comment: I dont understand your script. I didnt knew that you can pipe to a function and I dont understand how  it makes sence to echo before you get the answer . echo "$1" | bad_length && echo 'Password must be between 8 - 16 characters' && exit you put condition AND echo the  action at the same time. how does it even works ? logically

Comment: I've added a hopefully more understandable version.